# What is the 1st published example of Kal-El using the scientific method to benefit the general population of Earth?

Tags: dc, superman, science

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION-What is the first published example of Kal-El using the scientific method to benefit the general population of Earth? I'm looking for the first time it was noted, not an example published later and retroactively inserted into Superman's timeline.

When and what did Kal-El research to resolve and come up with a scientific solution that had to be applied meticulously to solve an issue to the  benefit of Earth's general population according to his timeline as it was published?

Comment: Nothing. Superman is generally a dick who keeps scientific advancements to himself.

Comment: I was able to trace him having "super-intelligence" as far back as 1956, which would be Golden Age, but I couldn't find any examples where he used it to benefit mankind. Or do anything important, actually.

Comment: @Omegacron looking more and more like hes just a dick as per cde haha

Comment: Does indirect benefit count? He used scientific method to do X that was required to stay alive, and clearly him being alive is a great benefit to population of Earth

Comment: lol. We could form a band: Major Stackings and the Crickets. You are all correct in your individual points of view, and yet, the vote count is woefully low.

Comment: At this point, I'd be happy to see a comic panel where Superman is just holding a test tube. The guy has a genius-level intellect, microscopic vision, can do mental calculations at super speed, and even has a "Super-Lab" in his Fortress of Solitude... yet never does science.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that super intelligence claim is alien propaganda.

Comment: @SJuan76 Edited. Attempted to clarify. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Superman does very little to help the population of Earth using his super-scientific expertise during the Silver Age of comics, but that is NOT an accident. He realizes he could destabilize humanity by introducing new sciences before we are ready for them.

- Superman, as a traveler to other worlds in the Silver Age has seen the effects of science on societies, particularly if those sciences are not closely monitored. Consider it a form of the Prime Directive.
- During the Silver Age, on the planet **[Colu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colu)**, computers took over from the superintelligent Coluans, and were subjugated by their creations, who now call themselves the Computer Tyrants of Colu. The Tyrants brainwashed the Coluans until the people of Colu were unaware that they were once masters of their planet.

[image]

- Superman does however engage in super-science and the scientific method, at least once during his career, reversing the shrinking of the Bottle City of Kandor from their miniaturized imprisonment by Brainiac.

Comment: Whew. I was afraid you were out fighting crime and this question wouldn't see an answer until your mission was accomplished.

Comment: ...and surrrrre... Help the Kandorians out, but leave the Earthlings swinging in the wind...

Comment: I am a crime fighter by night these days. My son is home for the summer.